# How to prevent the following regex from matching ellipses?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this regex:

```
(?<=[.?!])\.
```

To match the period that comes after the final punctuation in a sentence. Example:

> Sentence.. (The second period will be matched.)
>
> Sentence sentence?. (The period will be matched.)
>
> Sentence sentence!. (The period will be matched.)

It's been working fine so far ... except for ellipsis:

> Sentence sentence... (The last two periods will be matched.)

How to modify this regex so it doesn't match ellipsis `...`?

Live regex: https://regexr.com/6hf3n

Comment: Match it before matching the pattern you have now. Capture one part, use additional logic to handle the captured part. What is the expected result? If you want to remove dots after `.`, `?` and `!`, use `.replace(/(\.{3,})|(?<=[.?!])\./g, '$1')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already make use of a lookbehind, you might use:

```
(?<=[?!]|(?<!\.)\.(?!\.\.))\.
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is to the left is

  - `[?!]` Match either `?` or `!`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<!\.)\.(?!\.\.)` A dot when there is no dot to the left, and not 2 dot to the right
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\.` Match a dot

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sDTVkw/1).